# Get files list by mask with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a task get the list of files that matches some prefix. For now I made it like this:

```
$cache = get_dir_file_info($dir_path);      
$prefix = 'some_prefix';
foreach($cache as $info) {
    if(strpos($info['name'], $prefix) === 0) {
            ...do some things...
    }
}
```

I use Codeigniter 2 for this.

I know there is `php` function `array glob(string $pattern [, int $flags = 0])` but I want to do this with more "codeigniter way".

So my question is: can I get list of files at folder by mask with codeigniter?

Regards.

Comment: **get list of files** means what?? what list??

Comment: It means some kind of array. Its clear from code example i think.

Comment: where is the `dir_path` ???

Comment: Its some path inside application Like APPPATH.'cache/' for example.